# Build Hybrid Tree of Fruits

Tags: java, tree, linked-list

Ok so I have these interfaces and classes:

Code:

```
interface Tree extends Cloneable { int size(); }
class Fruit implements Tree {
@Override public int size() { 

return this.size();

}
}
class Branch implements Tree {
private List<Tree> children = new LinkedList<Tree>();
public List<Tree> getChildren() { return Collections.unmodifiableList(children); }
public void addChild(Tree tree) { children.add(tree); }
@Override public int size() { 

int size = 0;
for(Tree tree: children) size += tree.size();
return size;

}
}
class Mango extends Fruit { /* intentionally left empty */ }
class Peach extends Fruit { /* intentionally left empty */ }
```

And I need to create code that structures this type of hybrid tree:

- the trunk (main branch) of the tree

  - a branch with two mangoes
  - another branch with

    - a (sub)branch with two mangoes
    - one peach

I got the first part:

*Branch trunk = new Branch();*

But not sure how to code the next parts, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create each of the other objects and add them to the trunk. Use the `addChild(Tree tree)` method defined in Branch.

Some pseudocode:

```
make a branch for the trunk

make a branch
make two mangoes
add mangoes to branch
add the mango branch to the trunk

make a branch
make a peach
add peach to branch
make a sub-branch
make two mangoes
add mangoes to sub-branch
add sub-branch to branch
add branch to trunk
```

This is very procedural but is probably the most straightforward way given the code that you have. I would recommend that you consider making changes to the design if possible, but if this is a homework assignment you may be stuck with it.

The construction of this seems to more or less fit the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), as I read it.